How do you retrieve facebook graph api comment/like
I am currently trying to retrieve likes and comments for my post on facebook graph explorer. I get response bug, there is only my like, those other are missing whereas there is really much more likes.
Retrieving comment, all comments are on the response but, comment's authors are missing whereas I set in the field query.
These are the autorisation I set:

pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement

This is the response for likes requests from facebook explorer: /404084156710515_625686649729154?fields=comments{from,created_time},likes{id,name,username}
{
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2023-09-24T04:43:38+0000",
        "message": "comment1",
        "id": "625686649729154_1692834397884940"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2023-09-23T14:06:09+0000",
        "message": "comment2",
        "id": "625686649729154_326839209849302"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2023-09-22T15:47:49+0000",
        "message": "comment3",
        "id": "625686649729154_288127333934812"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "NgZDZD",
        "after": "MQZDZD"
      }
    }
  },
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "27817357317847681",
        "name": "ME"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "QVFIUnRwSFRRc0ZAfLTFVS24wUjRrb1FrZAzMyNzRsU3ZA1RE5MakFvYm42aUptS1EtUzhuWlJXMUlGVHBpd3h5c3pQWHdzMGNNcWlqSkg3UFJxbEdrTG5Kd3BB",
        "after": "QVFIUl9wanJEUDdON2tNV1JsRngyakdwZA1c2TENzTE95cUV6RHdGc01EdVhndWdmZAkduc3hWRFBGbTlrRTh3Yjl5YV9IaFV2VDlYcTAwTWxEeTNGdWxuc1ln"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/404084156710515_625686649729154/likes?access_token=<MY_TOKEN>&pretty=0&fields=id%2Cname%2Cusername&limit=25&after=QVFIUl9wanJEUDdON2tNV1JsRngyakdwZA1c2TENzTE95cUV6RHdGc01EdVhndWdmZAkduc3hWRFBGbTlrRTh3Yjl5YV9IaFV2VDlYcTAwTWxEeTNGdWxuc1ln"
    }
  },
  "id": "404084156710515_625686649729154"
}

I appreciate your help, thank you.
